# Django rest framework Post request

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am creating django + react app and i want to pass data by django rest framework.

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
class Address(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='address',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    apartment_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = CountryField(multiple=False)
    address_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ADDRESS_CHOICES)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Addresses'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.street_address, self.apartment_address, self.country, self.address_type)
```

**serializers.py**

````
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('street_address','apartment_address','country')
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model= User
        fields = ('email','username','password','address')```
````

**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class=UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

class AddressViewSet(APIView):


    def get(self, request, format=None):
        address = Address.objects.all()
        serializer = AddressSerializer(address, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AddressSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    @classmethod
    def get_extra_actions(cls):
        return []
```

My get request looks good because it returns value but it looks like something wrong is with **AddressSerializer(data=request.data)**

[image]

Comment: Why do you say it looks like something is wrong?

Comment: Instead of media type and content i want to have fields street_address apartament address and country

Answer (score 0):

Your `AdressSerializer` does not contains all the fields required in `Adress` model.

`AdressSerializer.create()` internally calls `Adress.create()`, that inevitably raise `ValidationError` if do not pass value for each required `field`

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
       model = Address
       fields = ('street_address','apartment_address','country') 
       # need 'username' and 'adress_type'
```